# Как получить нужный массив данных на PHP?

Tags: алгоритм, php, функции

Здравствуйте!

Имеется проблема. Есть масссив данных, который состоит из двух массивов. Нужно произвести манипуляции по склеиванию некоторых элементов.

Чтобы было понятнее, приведу пример:

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 2901
                    [ID_USER] => 2899
                    [CONFIG] => LowConfig
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 11539
                    [ID_USER] => 2899
                    [CONFIG] => LowConfig
                )
            )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 2901
                    [ID_USER] => 2899
                    [CONFIG] => MediumConfig
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => 11580
                    [ID_USER] => 2899
                    [CONFIG] => LowConfig

                )

        )
```

На выходе должен получится следующий массив:

```
[0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [ID] => 2901
                        [ID_USER] => 2899
                        [CONFIG] => LowConfig
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [ID] => 11539
                        [ID_USER] => 2899
                        [CONFIG] => LowConfig
                    )
               [2] => Array
                    (
                        [ID] => 11580
                        [ID_USER] => 2899
                        [CONFIG] => LowConfig

                    )
          )
```

Фактически `Array[n][0][n]` является главным элементом, по которому идет сравнение каждой пары. Как можно реализовать алгоритм, чтобы получился на выходе мой пример?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо `ID` подставить вместо ключа массива. Далее, merge по ключу.

```
function index(array $array, $key) {
    $result = array();
    foreach ($array as $element) {
        $value = $element[$key];
        $result[$value] = $element;
    }

    return $result;
}

$result = index($array1, 'ID') + index($array2, 'ID');
```

[Смотрите результат](http://ideone.com/BNb7PT).

Если данные приходят из БД, то, возможно, ваша ORM позволяет это делать. К примеру, в Yii2 AR, это [`indexBy()`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/db-active-record.md#querying-data-from-database).

Comment: Либо я уже сплю, либо Ваше решение не совсем подходит. Вы использовали 2 массива, у меня же он один. Первое это уникальный номер массива, в нем находится 2 массива (пара значений). Первый массив с ID = 0 является ключевым. Именно по нему ищем другие пары, у которые ID = 0, равен нашему ID = 0 и объединяем значения ID = 1 с самым первым.

Comment: @lolokot, почему у Вас массив с такой сложной иерархией? Откуда он берётся? Нельзя ли его упростить? Сколько в нём значений?

Comment: @lolokot, предлагаю схлопнуть его.

    $result = array();
    foreach ($data as $value) {
       $result += index($value, 'ID');
    }

[Смотрите результат](http://ideone.com/nkyvbp);

Comment: @romeo, в данном случаи идет один поток информации. В примере ID = 2901 служит для поиска такого же ID в других парах. Если ID такой найден в другой паре, то берем вторую часть из пары и добавляем к первой, если не нашли ничего не делаем.